# RegEx for matching a special pattern in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have code that extracts the text in different SGM files using the files Entity reference (&Ch1;). The code works great for this, but now it's expanded to need to get entity references for sectioned files with entity calls with this type of reference &Ch1-1; This can also grow to &Ch1-1-1;

I need to expand the code to accept these new entities so those files content can be added to the master file.

I believe the issue is the regular expression used so I changed it to

```
Dim rx = New Regex("&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+?[-\d+]?)?")
```

This doesn't create an error, but it also doesn't bring the file contents into the master document. I'm used to regular expressions but I've nevered used named capturing groups and found the explanations on the web a bit confusing.

```
Sub runProgram()
    Dim DirFolder As String = txtDirectory.Text
    Dim Directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(DirFolder)
    Dim allFiles As IO.FileInfo() = Directory.GetFiles("*.sgm")
    Dim singleFile As IO.FileInfo
    Dim Response As String


    Dim Prefix As String
    Dim newMasterFilePath As String
    Dim masterFileName As String
    Dim newMasterFileName As String
    Dim startMark As String = "<!--#start#-->"
    Dim stopMark As String = "<!--#stop#-->"
    searchDir = txtDirectory.Text
    Prefix = txtBxUnique.Text
    For Each singleFile In allFiles
        If File.Exists(singleFile.FullName) Then
            Dim fileName = singleFile.FullName
            Debug.Print("file name : " & fileName)
            ' A backup first    
            Dim backup As String = fileName & ".bak"
            File.Copy(fileName, backup, True)

            ' Load lines from the source file in memory
            Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(backup)

            ' Now re-create the source file and start writing lines inside a block
            Dim insideBlock As Boolean = False
            Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(backup)
                For Each line As String In lines
                    If line = startMark Then
                        ' start writing at the line below
                        insideBlock = True
                    ElseIf line = stopMark Then
                        ' Stop writing
                        insideBlock = False
                    ElseIf insideBlock = True Then
                        ' Write the current line in the block
                        sw.WriteLine(line)
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        End If
    Next

    masterFileName = Prefix & $"_Master_Document.sgm"
    newMasterFileName = Prefix & $"_New_Master_Document.sgm"
    newMasterFilePath = IO.Path.Combine(searchDir, newMasterFileName)

    Dim existingMasterFilePath = IO.Path.Combine(searchDir, masterFileName)


    'Read all text of the Master Document
    'and create a StringBuilder from it.
    'All replacements will be done on the
    'StringBuilder as it is more efficient
    'than using Strings directly
    Dim strMasterDoc = File.ReadAllText(existingMasterFilePath)
    Dim newMasterFileBuilder As New StringBuilder(strMasterDoc)

    'Create a regex with a named capture group.
    'The name is 'EntityNumber' and captures just the
    'entity digits for use in building the file name
    Dim rx = New Regex("&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(-?\d*)*)?")
    Dim rxMatches = rx.Matches(strMasterDoc)

    For Each match As Match In rxMatches
        Dim entity = match.ToString
        'Build the file name using the captured digits from the entity in the master file
        Dim entityFileName = Prefix & $"_Ch{match.Groups("EntityNumber")}.sgm.bak"
        Dim entityFilePath = Path.Combine(searchDir, entityFileName)
        'Check if the entity file exists and use its contents
        'to replace the entity in the copy of the master file
        'contained in the StringBuilder
        If File.Exists(entityFilePath) Then
            Dim entityFileContents As String = File.ReadAllText(entityFilePath)
            newMasterFileBuilder.Replace(entity, entityFileContents)
        End If
    Next


    'write the processed contents of the master file to a different file
    File.WriteAllText(newMasterFilePath, newMasterFileBuilder.ToString)

    Dim largeFilePath As String = newMasterFilePath
    Dim lines1 = File.ReadLines(largeFilePath).ToList 'don't use ReadAllLines
    Dim reg = New Regex("\<\!NOTATION.*$|\<\!ENTITY.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim entities = From line In lines1
                   Where reg.IsMatch(line)


    Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim idx = -1
    For Each s In entities
        idx = lines1.IndexOf(s, idx + 1)
        dictionary.Add(idx, s.Trim)
    Next

    Dim deletedItems = 0
    For Each itm In dictionary
        lines1.RemoveAt(itm.Key - deletedItems)
        deletedItems += 1
    Next

    Dim uniqueDict = dictionary.GroupBy(Function(itm) itm.Value).
    Select(Function(group) group.First()).
    ToDictionary(Function(itm) itm.Key, Function(itm) itm.Value)

    For Each s In uniqueDict.Values
        lines1.Insert(1, s)
    Next


    Dim builtMaster As String = Prefix & "_FinalDeliverable.sgm"
    Dim newBuiltMasterFilePath = IO.Path.Combine(searchDir, builtMaster)
    Dim builtMasterDoc As String = newBuiltMasterFilePath
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(builtMasterDoc)
        For Each line As String In lines1
            sw.WriteLine(line)
        Next
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
    End Using

    'Delete the master document and new master document

    If System.IO.File.Exists(existingMasterFilePath) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(existingMasterFilePath)
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(newMasterFilePath) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(newMasterFilePath)
    End If

    For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, "*.bak")
        IO.File.Delete(filename)
    Next


    Response = MsgBox("File 'FinalDeliverable.sgm' has been created.", vbOKOnly, "SGM Status")
    If Response = vbOK Then    ' User chose Yes.
        Close()
    Else    ' User chose No.
        ' Perform some action.
    End If
End Sub
```

The results I'm expecting is for files with names Ch1-1.sgm content between  and  content will be added to a master file.

This does work for file entities that are &Ch1; it grabs Ch1.sgm content correctly.

Thank you for the help,
Maxine

Sample Code:
Master_Document.sgm

```
<!DOCTYPE DOC PUBLIC "-//USA-DOD//DTD 38784STD-BV7//EN"[
]>
&Ch1;
<body numcols="2">
&Ch2-1;
&Ch2-2;
&Ch2-3;
&Ch2-4;
&Ch2-5;
&Ch2-6;
&Ch2-7;
&Ch2-8;
&Ch2-9;
&Ch3;
</body></doc>
```

Sample SGM file

```
 <?Pub /_gtinsert>                     
    <body numcols="2">                    
    <!--#start#-->                        
    <chapter id="Chapter_4__Procedures">  
    <title>Procedures</title>             
    <section>                             
    <title>Introduction</title>           
    <!--#stop#-->                         
    <para0 verdate="7 Never 2012" verstatu
    <title>Description</title>            
    <para>This chapterfor the following:
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through the code and see where it's failing?  Is it finding the matches?  Is it reading the entity number properly?  Is it formatting the filename properly?  By the way, based on your question, I would recommend changing your pattern to something like `&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(-?\d+)*)?`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could get rid of the named capture group by using a look-behind, like this: `(?<=&Ch)\d+(-?\d+)*`.  Then you could just read the whole `Match.Value`.

Comment: I get a file not found error. Saying it couldn't find the master document where it gets the entities from.But that's weird because in the immediate window it shows that file having been read.  I had tried using that regular expression the first time and didn't get any different results.

Comment: Could you please provide a very small, basic example input data and expected output? Note you do not need a named capturing group. The pattern to match `&Ch1-1;`  and `&Ch1-1-1;` is `&Ch(\d+(?:-\d+)*);`. Access using `match.Groups(1).Value`

Comment: I've pasted the main function of my code and the sample data. The master_document is where the code reads in the entity (&ch1;) then if finds the file in the same directory (ch1.sgm) and selects the text between the start and stop comments

Comment: Ok, it is now clear what you are doing. You may actually do all with a single `Regex.Replace` using MatchEvaluator as the replacement argument. However, it is a markup language, are you sure you can rely on regex here? I mean, are you sure all `&Ch2-1;` like things are to be replaced? What if they are inside comments?

Comment: It's worked so far. I didn't want to over complicate anything but if you have a better idea i'm all ears.

Comment: Ok use `&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(?:-\d+)*)`, with or without `;` at the end.

Comment: It's now throwing a file not found exception. I know the files there...I can see it. It's the Master_Document.sgm

Comment: That is no longer related to [regex](https://regex101.com/r/7nfc0L/1).

Comment: OK back to regex problem. I fixed the file

Comment: New Regex("& Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(?:-\d+)*")  I now get this error...parsing Not enough )'s

Comment: Use `New Regex("&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(?:-\d+)*)")`. Why didn't you copy/paste the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that `&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+?[-\d+]?)?` matched `&Ch` and then one or more, but as few as possible, digits (with `\d+?`) and then an optional single `-`, digit or `+` symbol. That is, after `&Ch`, only 1 digit was matched (as there is always a digit in your cases) and then a `-` was matched if it followed, and then matching stopped.

Use

```
Dim rx = New Regex("&Ch(?<EntityNumber>\d+(?:-\d+)*);")
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7nfc0L/2) and the regex graph:

[image]